# (3d object to json to webgl). Will I be able to manipulate skin of that 3d from webgl/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, three.js, webgl

Currently I don't have much experience on webgl that's why I'm asking this question.people may  be angry with me for this, my apology to them in advance.

Let's say I have a 3d object like a car or a human body. I then convert that 3d object to json for webgl.
Now if I do that (3d object to json to webgl). Will I be able to manipulate skin of that 3d  from webgl/javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to manipulate the material.

Take a look at: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cars

As you can see, each car is a single object that also holds informations about which triangle that model is made of corresponds to which material that is exported. There are many different ways to control the apperiance of the object, but the answer remains the same - it is possible, it's up to you to decide how're you gonna do it.

Hope this helps.